# be_directory failing in serverspec test

Tags: serverspec

I've got a *very* simple serverspec test below:

```
describe file('C:\\blah') do
  it { should exist }
  it { should be_directory }
end
```

However, the test is failing. I *know* that the directory exists. What's the deal?

```
     File "C:\blah"
       should exist (FAILED - 1)
       should be directory (FAILED - 2)
```

Comment: Try running the exact specinfra command: `Test-Path -Path C:\blah`. What is the output?

Comment: Yup I did indeed run that and it returns `true`

Comment: Serverspec is not related to Chef, do you have a question about Chef?

Comment: Are you perhaps testing on a server other than what you think you are testing on?

Comment: Hmm maybe. I think I don't have the appropriate directory structure as shown here http://serverspec.org/tutorial.html. Does it actually matter if the test is in `spec/{host}/{recipe}_spec.rb` structure? I already have a `spec` folder where we have `chefspec` tests.

Comment: Your test is executing, but the question is how and where. You would need to show your `Rakefile` and maybe `spec_helper` to help with that.

Comment: make sure you're setting your spec_helper.rb correctly with:
set :backend, :cmd
set :os, :family => 'windows'